# JavaScript stack overflow when dealing with a large dataset

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just created a small NodeJS application for doing some network IO and ran into what I believe is a stack overflow because of the number of callbacks.

My application is  basically a file transfer function composed of 2 network operations... lets call them `fetchData()` and `sendData()`. All they do is some HTTP Request to either GET or POST data.

I have my application setup like this:

```
function runTransfer(){
     // I need to transfer 100 million small documents
     // So I need to fetch and send a group (1000) at a time
     fetchData(fetchDataCallback);


    function fetchDataCallback(data){
         // Now that I have my data, lets send it to my other 'store'
         sendData(data, sendDataCallback);
     }

    function sendDataCallback(){
       // now that I got a 200 OK response we can fetch more data... and so on
       if(totalDocsFetched >= totalNumDocs){
             return; // This is where the application would finally end, once we fetched and sent all 100 million docs
       }
       fetchData(fetchDataCallback);


    }


}
```

Following this design pattern, I think that I would eventually get a stackoverflow because `fetchData -> fetchDataCallback -> sendData -> sendDataCallback -> fetchData -> fetchDataCallback -> sendData -> sendData...` and so forth until my stack explodes!

What kind of design pattern can I use here to ensure I don't get an overflow like this?

Comment: If the operations are asynchronous, then you cannot have a stack overflow because the previous `fetchDataCallback` will have returned long before the `sendDataCallback` runs.

Comment: You can't have a stack overflow in an async chain of callbacks

Comment: Ok well if my callbacks were anonymous functions instead, would it be possible to get an overflow of some kind because there would be thousands of definitions of the same fn?

Comment: no, if they're asynchronous you won't get an overflow or any kind of resource issue because the next callback can't happen until the callstack has cleared.

Comment: hmmmm.. thats strange cause I had my entire machine crash and restart on me while running the command.  I was ssh'd into the machine and didn't have a 'top' running so I wasn't sure if it was memory or what that caused it.

Comment: again, this all depends on whether or not it is asynchronous. If it's synchronous, you will get an overflow. but it does appear to be asynchronous.

Comment: Basically, you're not getting a stack overflow crash, it's more likely an unrelated memory leak in one of the other actions being performed, or too much data being stored at once for your server to handle.